# Как внедрить css и js на чужой сайт

Tags: javascript, html, браузер

Собственно вопрос в заголовке. Например нужно добавить

```
<script src="http://localhost/cur/jquery.cecutient.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/cur/jquery.cecutient.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('#cecutient').cecutient({
            increment: 1,
            target: "#layout article",
            imageClass: ".cecutientImagesOn",
            minimumFontSize : 0,
            maximumFontSize : 10,
            skipForFont: ".skip",
            container: "#panelWrapper",
            containerPath: "http://localhost/cur/templates",
            language: 'en'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Знаю есть плагины Greasemonkey и Stylish но есть вариант попроще через инспектор к примеру? И через локал хост скрипт не работает даже на моей странице?

Answer (score 2):

Во вкладке Sources консоли Google Chrome открываете нужный файл, добавляете нужный вам код. Жмете, CTRL+S и радуетесь. Для других браузеров наверняка есть что-то подобное, но точно сказать не могу

Comment: мне нужно добавить скрип и стиль в head и чтобы он там висел во время просмотра страниц

Comment: @Арсений в скрипте  `document.head.createElement ();`